# The maximum product lemma

Tags: number-theory

Let there be :
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n=x ,\text{where x is a constant}$$
Prove that the maximum value of the numbers' multiplication is achieved when they are all equal.
Is this available when the numbers are real or do they need to  be natural?Also a proof of this property would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard of the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: I did,but i didnt manage to use it  in order to solve this problem for n numbers.

Comment: Obviously if $n=5, x=41$ and $a_i\in\mathbb{N}$, the $a_i$s cannot be all equal, since $41\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, so your claim has to be fixed.

Comment: This implies that they have to be at least rational numbers.

Comment: You get the right spacing if you use `\ldots` instead of periods.

Comment: It also holds true for real numbers.

Comment: And , for real numbers, how can i prove this statement?